# Error message from Flask in Gunicorn in Docker

Tags: docker, flask, gunicorn

I have developed an app in Flask, which connects to a database. In development (in VS Code), if the app tries to connect to an incorrect ip-address for the database, I will get an error in the console. In 'production' where Flask runs under Gunicorn in a Docker container, where can I see this error message.

In the Docker setup I have a Dockerfile for defining the image and a compose file for executing the container. I have tried setting the --error-logfile in the Dockerfile on the CMD and also to set it as an environment variable in the settings file referenced in the YAML file. In any case, I cannot find out where to see the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see your logs with [docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) or [docker-compose logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_logs/) : `docker logs -f <YOUR CONTAINER>`.
With this commands, you'll see all your errors and shell messages.

If you want to access your file inside your Docker container, you can run [this command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) to go inside your container : `docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID> bash` and then go to your log file directory and display it.